# trying to shrink div width and height by 50 but not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to shrink div width and height by 50 and it's not working, someone knows why?

```js
function onBall2Click() {
  var ball = document.querySelector('.ball2');

  //  alert('Ball2');
  ball2Size = ball2Size + 50;
  ball.innerText = ball2Size;
  ball.style.width = ball2Size;
  ball.style.height = ball2Size;


  // when ball size reach 400 shrink him by 50

  if (ball2Size == 400) {
    ball2Size = ball2Size - 50;
  }
  // when ball size reach 100, grow by 50
  // } else if (ball2Size == 100) {
  //     ball2Size = ball2Size + 50;
  // }

}
```

```html
<div class="ball2" onclick="onBall2Click()">
  TOGGLE
</div>
```

Comment: You have to add `px` to the end of the sizes.

Comment: ball2Size  is never set, where does it come from?

Comment: `ball2Size = ball2Size + 50;` where is the initial value coming from? Is it a string or a number?

Comment: You "overwrite" the `- 50` on the next click with `+ 50`. You won't ever see a smaller baller with that setup.

Comment: Hey David, there is a , var ball2Size = 100; in the start of the script tag

Comment: @Dor: if it's not in the code you provided as the [mcve] code of your question (see the guidelines) it doesn't exist so far as your question's code is concerned. If it's there, add it to your code.

Answer (score 0):

As much as javaScript is flexible, you can't use undeclared variables.
The error you are having is...

```
ReferenceError: ball2Size is not defined
```

You will have to declare the variable first.
Here is how your code would look like

```
let ball2Size = 0 //this will fix it
function onBall2Click() {
        var ball = document.querySelector('.ball2');

        //  alert('Ball2');
        ball2Size = ball2Size + 50;
        ball.innerText = ball2Size;
        ball.style.width = ball2Size;
        ball.style.height = ball2Size;


        // when ball size reach 400 shrink him by 50

        if (ball2Size == 400) {
            ball2Size = ball2Size - 50;
        }
        // when ball size reach 100, grow by 50
        // } else if (ball2Size == 100) {
        //     ball2Size = ball2Size + 50;
        // }

    }
```

Comment: Hey, sry i didn't mention but i did declare the ball2Size at the start of the script, it"s var ball2Size = 100;

Comment: It should still work.
 Check where your script is in your HTML file, be sure it is at the bottom of the body tag.